# Inserting current GMT time in React DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

Im using [React DatePicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-date-picker) for the React project the current time in GMT should also be selected along with it. Please help me out!

```
    handleValueChanges = (src, e) => {
        let formEdit = {}
        formEdit = { ...this.state.formData }
        if (src === 'from_tstamp' || src === 'to_tstamp') {
            formEdit[src] = e
        } else {
            formEdit[src] = e.target.value
        }
        this.setState({
            formData: formEdit
        },()=>console.log(this.state.formData.to_tstamp))
        
    }

<DatePicker placeholderText="mm/dd/yyyy" className="form-control" dateFormat='MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'  selected={this.state.formData.to_tstamp} onChange={(date) => this.handleValueChanges('to_tstamp', date)} 

/>
```

[image]
See the selected time is in 00:00:00 but I want the current GMT time to be set. Please help. Im a newbie.

`handleValueChanges` method stores the selected date in a state, which is in the format of `Wed Mar 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use DateTimePicker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-picker) for time selection. If the request is updated with the current time when the date is selected, you can use the .setHours (new Date (). GetHours ()), .setMinutes (new Date (). GetMinutes ()) .... methods.